# Django ORM executes query with wrong time?

Tags: django, django-orm, datetime-format

I am trying to fetch data based on *DateTime* Field! I wrote the following script for the same:

```
import datetime as dt

from dasboard.models import Visionsystem 
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware

min_dt = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), dt.time(7, 15))
max_dt = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), dt.time(15, 44))

# Changing format for Django
min_dt_aware = make_aware(min_dt)
max_dt_aware = make_aware(max_dt)

# Fetching all the data between 7:15:00 to 15:44:00 for current day
l1 = Visionsystem.objects.filter(start_datetime__range=(min_dt_aware, max_dt_aware))
```

***print(l1)*** yields *empty list* and Checking ***str(l1.query)*** gives:

```
'SELECT `visionsystem`.`id`, `visionsystem`.`Start_Datetime` ... FROM `visionsystem` WHERE 
`visionsystem`.`Start_Datetime` BETWEEN 2019-10-16 01:45:00 AND 2019-10-16 10:14:00'
```

Desired query would be:

```
'SELECT `visionsystem`.`id`, `visionsystem`.`Start_Datetime` ... FROM `visionsystem` WHERE 
`visionsystem`.`Start_Datetime` BETWEEN 2019-10-16 07:15:00 AND 2019-10-16 15:44:00'
```

I don't understand why *Django-ORM* is querying with a *different time* then what's specified ?

My timezone settings ( in *settings.py* ):

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

How do I resolve this, to fetch the required data from *7:15:00* to *15:44:00*, for *current day* ? NOTE: I am using *MySQL Database*!!

***models.py*** *file*:

```
    from django.db import models

    class Visionsystem(models.Model):

        start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Start_Datetime', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'visionsystem'
```

Comment: Can you show your Visionsystem models.py file?

Comment: Also, are you using SQLite or Postgres for your database?

Comment: @NicoGriffioen I have added the code for models.py file!! And I am using MySQL Database!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short

1. Django saves store UTC in database.
2. If you don't mention a timezone, the timezone you mentioned in settings.py is taken (in your case, `Asia/Kolkata` is taken, so make_aware function assumes, you are entering a datetime with timezone `Asia/Kolkata`. But as mentioned in step 1., it is saved as UTC. Both time points to same time - that is, time described by both UTC and Asia/Kolkata is same).
3. In addition to both 1 and 2, django convert your timezone_aware datetime (ie. min_dt_aware and max_dt_aware) to UTC, to make the correctness of your query during query execution.

Here is the detailed explanation.

**Time zones overview**

When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores date-time information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware date-time objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

Value is shown as UTC, which is printed in SQL query:

```
import pytz
utc = pytz.UTC
# Print the utc value of min_dt_aware and max_dt_aware
print(min_dt_aware.astimezone(utc), max_dt_aware.astimezone(utc))
# So, as you can see, these utc values are which you see in SQL queries.
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview


http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

https://tommikaikkonen.github.io/timezones/

Comment: SOrry. I was really, pissed off, since, I couldn't add this links to answer. [Since, SO, see these links as some programming language code]

Comment: Any way, these links in the comments are the explanation to my answer. Or the place to learn more useful information about timezone handling in django.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer, along with the relevant links! I was aware of the MySQL Timezone limitation

Comment: Well, I had to convert TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' to get it working!

Answer (score 3):

MySql doesn't supports timezones, It stores datetime in UTC, while your django 
 application timezone is `Asia/Kolkata` (UTC +5:30).

Here django automatically converts your application timezone to UTC before querying to MySQL database. This makes sense as when you save data using django application, it converts datetime to UTC time, so `07:15:00 Kolkata` time would be stored as `01:45:00` in UTC.

**Solution:**

You can store MySql data in UTC timezone, If existing data is in `Kolkata` timezone, run update query by subtracting `-5:30` and save all new data in UTC timezone.

OR

If your application doesn't need to support multiple timezone, you can change application timezone to `UTC`. This is quick solution but not a good idea as timezone information is truncated.

Comment: Because of certain constraints( Another application writing to this table), 1st Solution isn't feasible for me!! Exploring 2nd solution!!

Comment: Actually in that case you should ask another application team to convert datetime to UTC and store in database, as this is data error. If you can not request them, then you can do a hack using switching django application timezone, `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  timezone.now(), it worked for me. For this first you need to import timezone,from django.utils import timezone https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/